# unknown type name ‘GtkSourceCompletionWords’ in vala gtk

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying the code -

```
var prov_words = new SourceCompletionWords (null, null);
```

I get error:

> error: unknown type name ‘GtkSourceCompletionWords’

The [docs](https://valadoc.org/gtksourceview-3.0/Gtk.SourceCompletionWords.html) show the `sourcecompletionwords` class to be public

Could this be a versions problem ? Any pointers to fix will be helpful.

I am compiling by including the package -

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0  --pkg gtksourceview-3.0 gtk-sourceview-sample.vala
```

Comment: Do you have the dev package installed? If so, check the vapi file and look if there is that same class. Maybe the version on valadoc differs from the one you have installed.

Comment: hey jose fonte - no i didnt install the package. other features of gtksourceview work for me. only GtkSourceCompletionWords built in provider doesnt work.
Can you please give me more detail - what is a dev package?
Also this class works for me in pygtk library - i just built pygobject.

Please tell me what is dev package and how to install it.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: with dev package i meant devel package, these are packages used for development. PyGObject uses gobject introspection. Vala uses VAPI files to map methods into the C function names. You should check if you have the development package, if so, check the VAPI file for the class you are trying to use (these are text files, grep them for the class and/or methods). You must also check if the version you're using is the latest available.

Comment: Thanks buddy.
I didnt know vapi files are for this purpose.
i will try to make this work when i hack on vala again in this week.
I shall see how to install the devel package as surely i have not done this.
maybe jhbuild will install it for me.
I have started using jhbuild now as it looks good.
cheers.